# Is it possible/wise to build a mobile website with jquerymobile, ajax and jquery bbq?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, jquery-bbq

I have a website intended for desktops/laptops, built with jquery and jquery bbq.

I now want to produce a mobile version of this site and am planning to use jquerymobile. However, I'm a little scared to see href="#" links in some of the documentation, as I'm already manipulating the location hash to provide back/forward/bookmarking with jquery bbq.

Are these technologies compatible or am I heading for a world of trouble?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: jQuery mobile definitely utilises the `href="#pagename"` to load and transition between pages. Whether one can be overridden/disabled, I am unsure.

Comment: yep, that's my worry.. I'm wondering if perhaps you can merge your own #parameters in with jquerymobile or something like that. I'll do some more research, but just wondered if anyone had some experience of trying it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decided not to mix the two, going to keep my mobile application simple.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the trouble. The `href="#"` is only a way to say that this is a link that doesn't do anything.
It's an old tradition to say `href="#"` instread of `href=""`.

Comment: not to mention some versions of IE can have wierd hissy fits and loose cookies if you use null hrefs or img src attributes. Only ever witnessed it twice but that's what it turned out to be. A bit OT but nevertheless...

Comment: Doesn't jquerymobile use href="#" to switch between pages? For example, to link to the page with an id of "two", my link would have a href="#two"